# Multivariate regression with categorical response variables

Tags: r, classification, multiple-regression, categorical-data

Explanation of Data:
I started with a data set where each user belong a specific group and their contribution to different domains. After multiple pivots and pre-processing attempts, I got my data in format where I can use it in a regression.

```
  user_id    X0   X1   X2  X3   X4  X5 X6 X7  X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 group
1       2 33653 2325  916 720  867 187 31  0   6  3  42  56  92  15  69   0   A
2       4 18895  414 1116 570 1190  55 92  0 122 23  78   6   4   2  11   0   B
3      16  1383   70   27  17   17   1  0  0   0  0   1   0   0   0   3   0   C
4      50   396   72   34   5   18   0  0  0   0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   A
5      51  3915 1170  402 832 2791 316 12  5 118 51  32   9  62  27   1   0   D
6      57   554   33  138  13  415   4  5  0   0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   E
7      79  5707  113  362   87   59   5  0  0   0  0   6   1   0   0  13   3  E
8      83 10225 2447  133  684  877 314  0  1   5  5   0   0  18   4   0   0  A
9     100  2759 1201  369 1237 1604 822  2  0   0  0  60   2   0   2   3   0  B
10    107   173   19   27    6    6   0  0  0   0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0  B
11    113   114   17   27    2    5   2  0  0   0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0  A
12    119   514   36   21  206    9   4  3  0   0  0   6   0   0   0   0   0  D
```

Basically its a multi-class problem. In my problem I have 6 classes that users are belong to.

My goal is to run regression to understand if any of the X0-X15 features are good predictors to identify a group that user is belong to. This could a combination of X0-X15 in the regression model such as `group ~ X0 + X2 + ..` etc.

But the in regression response variable has to be a continuous variable. What is the best way to model this problem? Where I can use a combination of features to predict the grup that user belong to?

I started to read following paper: http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ordered.pdf and I am not sure thats relevant to what I am trying to do.

Comment: Is above your entire data or is this just a sample of the data?

Comment: @mso its a sample of the data. Data is too large to paste.

Comment: I am not an expert but why not following command : summary(glm(group~., data=ddf[,-1], family='binomial'))

Comment: If groups are ordered, this column can be converted to numbers using command: mydata\$gp2 = sapply(mydata\$group, function(x) which(LETTERS == x))  ;  Then following will work: summary(lm(gp2~., data=ddf[,-c(1,18)]))